# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

In my HomeController.cs I set *Session*:

```
public IActionResult Index(Mod m)
{
    if (m.Password == "1234")
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Login", "True");
        ViewBag.Login = "True";
    }
    ...
}
```

and I want to change *Session* values in JavaScript:

```
...
<input type="submit" value="Login" asp-for="Login" />

<a href="#" id="submit-link" class="button" onclick="submit();">Logout</a>
...

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit() {
        var v = '@Context.Session.GetString("Login")';
        alert(v);
        '@Context.Session.SetString("Login", "False")'; // ERROR --> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'
    }
</script>
```

*Session.GetString* works fine, but *Session.SetString* has error. I dont't know how to convert *void* to *object* here.

Comment: The error happens because the Razor engine wants to _render_ something there but there is nothing being returned by your method call to render. – To save you the troubles here though: This approach is not going to work. You cannot make a call to some server-side method from within a JavaScript handler that runs on the client. By putting the method call into your Razor view, you are running that method at the time the Razor view is being rendered by the server, which happens way before the user is even able to see and click your button. – Look into form submisssions or AJAX calls here instead.

Comment: I tried to make various tests on my side to set the session in asp.net core from the JS code. It looks like directly it is not possible to set the session using the JS code. I would suggest you set the session in the C# code or you could try to set some values in the Js for example some global variable and then try to access that variable in C# to set the session.